# Slatejs deserialize break line as new fragment

Tags: javascript, slate.js

I am working with slatejs, and I have the following html line, 
`<p>Line one<br /> Line two</p>`

My current rule for `br` is the following,

```
deserialize(el, next) {
    const block = BLOCK_TAGS[el.tagName.toLowerCase()];
    if (!block) return;
    return {
        kind: 'block',
        type: block,
        nodes: next(el.childNodes),
    };
},

const BLOCK_TAGS = {
  p: 'paragraph',
  li: 'list-item',
  ul: 'bulleted-list',
  ol: 'numbered-list',
  blockquote: 'quote',
  pre: 'code',
  h1: 'heading-one',
  h2: 'heading-two',
  h3: 'heading-three',
  h4: 'heading-four',
  h5: 'heading-five',
  h6: 'heading-six',
  br: 'br',
}
```

But this creates a empty line, that causes issues on backspace, I have tried passing a new block in my serialize, but that gave me the same result.

What should my deserialize rule be so that my text is rendered as following in the slate editor.

```
Line one
Line two
```

Comment: What is the value of `BLOCK_TAGS`?

Comment: @IanStormTaylor I added the block tag to the code. I am also using version 21.5

Comment: @IanStormTaylor is there a way to determine the Slate version via the console?